# Roundy or curly arrow which indicates or connects the formulas by jumping over row(s)

Tags: arrows

I've written below codes and got the below image.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw(0,10)node[right]{$y=f(x)$};

        \draw(0,9)node[right]{$=a x ^{2}+ x$};
        
        \draw[blue,->] (0,9) to[bend right=60] (0,7);

        \draw(0,8)node[right]{$a \in\mathbb{R}\setminus 0 $};

        \draw(0,7)node[right]{$=a \left( x ^{2} +\frac{x}{a}   \right) $};        

    \end{tikzpicture}

    $\displaystyle $\\

    $\displaystyle y=f(x)$\\

    $\displaystyle =a x ^{2} +x$\\
    
    $\displaystyle a \in\mathbb{R}\setminus 0 $\\

    $\displaystyle y=a \left( x ^{2} +\frac{x}{a}   \right) ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{Quite annoying to write again}~~ y$\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to do the same thing by more simpler way.

Is it able to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with the `witharrows` package

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{DispWithArrows*}[displaystyle]
    y & = f(x) \\
    & = a x ^{2} +x \Arrow[tikz={blue,font={\small}}]{$ a \in\mathbb{R}\setminus 0 $} \\
    & = a \left( x ^{2} +\frac{x}{a} \right)
\end{DispWithArrows*}

\end{document}
```

[image]